# Thread has exited with code 0 but not finished it's work

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm kinda new to multi- threading in C# and would like to know why is this behavior happening:

**I have thread 1 to load files asynchronously. Thread 2 is meant to always check if thread is still running and if thread 1 stopped running that it should update UI.**

Now, I know there are better ways to achieve what I want using Tasks or other mechanisms, but once I encounter this issue I need to know what am I doing wrong using this implementation first, before learning the better ways to do it.

**The problem is that sometimes it executes perfectly fine and at other times the threads just exit with code 0 without updating my UI to notify it finished working.**

actual code:

```
 // Call File Manager (singleton) Async file loader method from the MainWindow.cs class
    fm.loadFromDirAsync(new DirectoryInfo(dialog.SelectedPath));


 // This method is in the File Manager singleton class
public void loadFromDirAsync(DirectoryInfo di)
{
    loadFiles = new Thread(() => FullDirList(di, "*.mp3"));
    loadFiles.Start();
    loadFiles.Name = "loadFromDirAsync";

}

// Back to MainWindow class, start a new thread to check if the async load thread 
   is still running:

          // Check if finished loading
    Thread t = new Thread(() => load());
    t.Start();
    t.Name = "LoaderThread";


// this method (in MainWindow class) checks if the loader thread in File Manager is still alive:
           private void load()
{
    while (runCheck)
    {

        // If Async file loading thread finished...
        if (!fm.isThreadStillLoading())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done running");

            Dispatcher.Invoke(
              System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
             new Action(
        delegate()
        {
            loadBTN.IsEnabled = true;
            pb.IsIndeterminate = false;
            pb.IsEnabled = false;
            runCheck = false;
            pbLabel.Content = string.Format("Finished Indexing {0} files in {1} folder - Ready to play.", fm.filesCount, fm.foldersCount);

        }
         ));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would indeed be perfect for TPL ;) But even without, the `loadFromDirAsync` function could include a delegate to invoke on finish. Anyway, to see where the current setup might go wrong, can you include where runCheck is set. It could be that the thread sometimes starts before runCheck is set and sometimes just after. (And do both threads exit right away, or only the UI update checker? )

Comment: runCheck starts as a class variable set to true; Only if Thread 1 (loadFromDirAsync thread) is finished, then (!fm.isThreadStillLoading) should be true and therefor update the UI. But sometimes it just seems like the thread got stuck and exited (code 0) in the MIDDLE of the operations.

Comment: and `fm.isThreadStillLoading` is also based on a preset boolean?

Comment: It returns     
            return (loadFiles.IsAlive);

Comment: TBH I've just tried using Task and it works perfectly. I'm just very interested to know whats wrong with what I've done as it seems correct.

Comment: Just guessing here, but I think that sometimes your reading thread wasn't started yet, and the UI checking thread was ahead, so loadFiles.IsAlive returned false, immediately updating the UI, but because the mainwindow wasn't fully loaded yet, the changes were overridden. To be sure that's the problem, you could testing by replacing the IsAlive with a (static) boolean.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is, I only changed Thread t = new Thread() to Task t = new Task in all places I had started a thread and it now works perfectly.